# the least flare-up and off it came

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is from the book 'In cold blood' by Truman Capote

Now, Upstairs, she changed into faded Levis and a green sweater, and fastened round her wrist her third-most-valued belonging, a gold watch; her closest cat friend, Evinrude, ranked above it, and surmounting even Evinrude was Bobby's signet ring, the cumbersome proof of her "going-steady" status, which she wore
(**when she wore it; the least flare-up and off it came**) on a thumb, for even with the use of adhesive tape its man-size girth could not be made to fit a more suitable finger.

"when she wore it; **the least flare-up and off it came**"

I wonder what this sentence means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways it could be interpreted.

She wears the ring as a symbol of 'going steady' (going out seriously, rather than just dating) with Bobby. But the sentence "when she wore it" implies she doesn't wear it all the time. She takes it off when there's any small 'flare-up'.

> Flare-up: a sudden outburst of something, especially violence or hostility (*Google dictionary*)

1. A flare-up could mean an argument between them ("tempers flaring up" is a common way to talk about getting angry). That makes sense — she's cross with him, and doesn't want to be reminded of him by wearing his ring.
2. A 'flare up' can be a colloquial way of saying a skin condition has got worse e.g

> her eczema had flared up; she's having a bad flare-up of dermatitis

so it could be that her skin is inflamed and sore, and she doesn't want to wear a ring that might irritate it.

If the book doesn't mention she has a skin condition, I'd assume it's the first one.